# Best Practice for Customising Component Styling in Ionic 4

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am looking for best practice for changing component styling in Ionic 4, such as font size. I've read many sources but not clear on what the best approach is.

As I understand it, there is an SCSS file for each component that can be used to set styling for that component, and `global.scss` for global changes.

Are there any special considerations here? For example, is using element names appropriate or should classes be preferred?

What about when the styling varies between platforms? Is that best done with something like...

```
ion-card-header {
    .ios & {

    }
    .md & {

    }
}
```

To change globally, add it to the global SCSS?

Also how to work appropriately with CSS variables.

Looking for thoughts and best practices please, and any considerations special to the structure of Ionic 4.

Answer (score 3):

I am having a go at answering this myself, to collect the information I have been looking at.

**Utility Attributes** - *`text-wrap`, `no-padding` etc.*

Ionic 4 includes a number of [utility attributes](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities) that can be used to modify elements where they are available. Examples include `text-wrap` or `padding-start`.

These can be applied to any element, to adjust the styling by using an attribute. This is the preferred approach for changes that only apply to a single case, and would not benefit from a rule.

The utilities include:

- Text Modification

  - text-center, text-wrap, text-capitalize etc.
- Element Placement

  - float-left, float-end etc.
- Content Space

  - padding-start (adds 16px padding at start), no-padding, margin-bottom etc.
- Flex Properties

  - justify-content-evenly, align-items-baseline, nowrap, align-self-center etc.

For the text modification and element placement attributes, they have responsive versions, such as `text-lg-center` or `float-sm-end`.

**CSS Variables** - *`--color`, `--padding-start` etc.*

Ionic 4 is built using [CSS Variables](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables) ([more on CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)), replacing SCSS variables and enabling runtime changes.

**Global CSS Variables** - *`--ion-color-primary`, `--ion-color-primary-contrast` etc.*

- Colour Variables

  - --ion-color-primary, --ion-color-primary-contrast etc.
- Application Variables

  - --ion-font-family, --ion-grid-padding-md etc.

These are described in more detail below.

**Global Colour CSS Variables**

Theme colours should be used for any colour that is used throughout your application. Ionic 4 provides 9 theme colours out of the box, which can be used to change the colour of many components. Examples include:

```
<ion-button>Default</ion-button>
<ion-button color="primary">Primary</ion-button>
<ion-button color="secondary">Secondary</ion-button>
<ion-button color="tertiary">Tertiary</ion-button>
<ion-button color="success">Success</ion-button>
<ion-button color="warning">Warning</ion-button>
<ion-button color="danger">Danger</ion-button>
<ion-button color="light">Light</ion-button>
<ion-button color="medium">Medium</ion-button>
<ion-button color="dark">Dark</ion-button>
```

**Modifying Colour Variables**

You should set all of appropriate variables when changing a colour, such as...

```
:root {
  --ion-color-secondary: #006600;
  --ion-color-secondary-rgb: 0,102,0;
  --ion-color-secondary-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-secondary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
  --ion-color-secondary-shade: #005a00;
  --ion-color-secondary-tint: #1a751a;
}
```

The [colour generator](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/color-generator) can be used to generate these for a base colour. It can't be done with SCSS because it needs to work at runtime. Solutions to support this [are being worked on](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3187).

**Adding Colours**

New colours that are used throughout your application [can be added](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/advanced#adding-colors), as an alternative to modifying a default colour.

**Modifying the Background Colour or Text Colour**

When modifying the background colour or text colour variable, a large set of stepped colours also [need to be updated](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/advanced#stepped-colors). An example is...

```
:root {
    --ion-background-color: #ffffff;
    --ion-background-color-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --ion-text-color: #000000;
    --ion-text-color-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --ion-color-step-50: #f2f2f2;
    --ion-color-step-100: #e6e6e6;
    --ion-color-step-150: #d9d9d9;
    --ion-color-step-200: #cccccc;
    --ion-color-step-250: #bfbfbf;
    --ion-color-step-300: #b3b3b3;
    --ion-color-step-350: #a6a6a6;
    --ion-color-step-400: #999999;
    --ion-color-step-450: #8c8c8c;
    --ion-color-step-500: #808080;
    --ion-color-step-550: #737373;
    --ion-color-step-600: #666666;
    --ion-color-step-650: #595959;
    --ion-color-step-700: #4d4d4d;
    --ion-color-step-750: #404040;
    --ion-color-step-800: #333333;
    --ion-color-step-850: #262626;
    --ion-color-step-900: #191919;
    --ion-color-step-950: #0d0d0d;
}
```

These can be [easily generated](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/advanced#generate-stepped-color-variables).

**Global Application CSS Variables**

A number of global [application variables](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/advanced#application-variables) are available. These should be used where they can be. Examples include `--ion-font-family`, `--ion-padding` and `--ion-margin`. Those last two modify the values used by the utility attributes for padding and margin that were discussed above.

**Global Grid CSS Variables**

A number of global [grid variables](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/advanced#grid-variables) are available. These should be used where they can be. Examples include `--ion-grid-columns` and `--ion-grid-padding-xl`.

**Component CSS Variables**

The CSS Variables that a component accepts can be found in the Custom Properties section of its entry in the [API Reference](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/).

For example, see the [Custom Properties for ion-button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button#css-custom-properties), such as `--ripple-color` or `--color-activated`.

**Setting CSS Variables**

To set global variables, use the `src/theme/variables.scss` file, and set them on the `:root` selector, such as...

```
:root {
  /* Set the font family of the entire app */
  --ion-font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Helvetica Neue", "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
```

To set component variables, use the component selector, such as...

```
/* Set the color on all ion-button elements */
ion-button {
  --color: #222;
}
```

CSS variables should be used to modify components where they are available.

**Getting CSS Variables**

To get a CSS variable, the [var() CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) should be used, which allows any number of fallback values, such as...

```
.fancy-button {
  --background: var(--charcoal, #36454f);
}
```

**Platform Styling**

Platform specific styling should be changed using the `.ios` and `.md` selectors, such as:

```
.ios ion-badge {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Global variables should be used for this where they are available, such as:

```
.ios {
  --ion-background-color: #222;
}
```